# Как повторить элементы списка заданное количество раз? (python)

Tags: python

Есть два списка одинаковой длины. Первый содержит строковые значения (str). Второй численные (int). Необходимо создать третий список, в котором необходимо повторить строковые значения из первого списка столько раз, сколько указано во втором списке.
**Например:**
***На входе:***

```
a=["A","B","C"]
b=[2,3,2]
```

***На выходе:***

```
c=["A","A","B","B","B","C","C"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не запариваться с однострочными программами, то самый типичный код для такой ситуации будет выглядеть так:

```
x = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    x += [a[i]]*b[i]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это решение делает в точности то что требовалось!

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = [2, 3, 4]
d = []
for x in range(len(a)):
    d.append(a[x] * b[x])
```

Достаточно легко можно сделать с помощью оператора `for`
Дополняю вопрос про команды `append` и `extend`

Команда `append` полностью всё предложение кидает в одну ячейку списка, а
`extend` как раз раскидивает символы на каждую ячейку списка.
Для двух размерного массива

```
a=[["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"]]
b=[[2,3,2],[2,3,4]]
d = []
k = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for x in range(len(a[i])):
        k.extend(a[i][x] * b[i][x])
    d.append(k)     
print(d)
```

Comment: Не совсем то что мне нужно. При таком исполнении получается список из трех элементов. d=["aa","bbb","cccc"] А задача состоит в том, что бы на выходе получилось d=["a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"]

Comment: Стоит всего заменить на extend

Answer (score 1):

Можно в одну строчку, если захотелось побаловаться функциональным программированием

```
print(list(map(lambda x, y: [c for c in x] * y, ["A","B","C"], [2,3,2])))
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Это то что нужно!

Comment: @MTX Пожалуйста :)

Comment: Вывод не соответствует требованию в вопросе.

Comment: Я пригляделся и понял, что данная функция на выходе создает список из списков. Не совсем то, что нужно. Но все равно большое спасибо за отклик!

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import starmap, chain

a, b = ["A","B","C"], [2,3,2]
print(list(chain(*map(list, starmap(mul, zip(a, b))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант с `zip`:

```py
a = ["A","B","C"]
b = [2,3,2]
c = [x for i, j in zip(a, b) for x in [i] * j]
print(c)
# ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

с библиотекой itertools можно ужаться до такого кода:

```
from itertools import repeat,chain

a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = [2, 3, 4]

c = [*chain(*map(repeat,a,b))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если делать по простому, то получится такой код:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b = [2, 3, 2]

c = []
for s, k in zip(a, b):
    c.extend(s * k)
print(c)
```

Если хочется в одну строку, то так:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b = [2, 3, 2]

c = [s for s, k in zip(a, b) for _ in range(k)]
print(c)
```